# keyless entry, when keys are inside car

Tags: honda, keyless-entry

So I tend to take naps in my car when I'm on college campus. My car is a 2019 Honda Insight which operates on keyless entry. So if my keys are inside my car, can somebody still unlock my car when they touch the handle?

If so, I'm gonna go find myself a metal can or aluminium foil.....

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As HandyHowie has stated, try it. I'd suggest someone could most likely do this, as the key would be in the proximity of the vehicle. Sounds like a good way to have a "rude awakening" if you ask me.

Comment: You don't even need a helper - just lock up normally with you inside, open a window and reach out.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your car thinks you aren't in it the alarm may arm.

Comment: A metal can or aluminum foil often isn't enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My "fleet" consists of a pair of 2013 Rav4EVs with keyless "ignition" that also has the touch sensor on the door handles. When my wife arrived this evening, I had her lock the doors with the vehicle in the running mode.

No key fob in my pocket and the doors remained locked.

With the power off, no key fob, the doors remained locked. Obviously, her fob was inside the vehicle.

It seems reasonable to believe that other and newer models would behave in a similar manner.

Comment: Very nice anecdotal evidence. Thanks for testing :o)